# What does 暴走 mean in 这就是让卡罗琳听到，估计也会暴走?

Tags: meaning

What does 暴走 mean? I tried searching and it said something about running away.

This is the full sentence:

> 这就是让卡罗琳听到，估计也会暴走。

Comment: “暴走”最早是个日语词，被中国人所熟知很可能来自于动画《新世纪福音战士》。

Answer (score 5):

> [暴走](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%9A%B4%E8%B5%B0/649) (literally mean: "wildly run" )（动漫术语)

It is a Japanese anime/manga lingo that imported to Chinese. The Chinese equivalent of "暴走" is "失控" (out of control; lose control)

暴走 means "out of control" - (also, 'act violently' is implied. The obvious sign of someone is out of control is not following the common sense and/or act violently)

*暴走族 (clan that run wildly) is a Japanese term for "bike gang", the Chinese equivalent of "暴走族" is "飛車黨"*

Answer (score 4):

It is a Japanese anime word that is adopted to Chinese. It has a similar meaning as the English word rampage, but can be used to an individual. i.e. a period of violent and uncontrollable behavior

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Do you know this game - King of Fighters?

In this game, when the bottom power slot is full, you can brust it. The mandarin people call it "brust the bean"(爆豆), in my dialect, it's called "brust the slot"(炸管儿.)
Whatever it is called, after brusting it, your role gets into a rage mode -- maybe moving faster, maybe having heavier ATK, maybe haing some special skills. This mode you can call it 暴走模式 (furious mode) - you can think of Hulk mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think "berserk" would be a very fitting translation.

这就是让卡罗琳听到，估计也会暴走。
"I guess even Caroline will go berserk if she heard about this."

Answer (score -1):

1. In Chinese, 暴走=暴+走，暴means blastly,ballistically。So 暴走 means walk blastly （still walk rather run）。This expression is not so popular in formal Chinese, only the case of 暴走族，meaning a group of people exercising by walking very fastly.
2. Your sentence:这就是让卡罗琳听到，估计也会暴走, is not popular in formal Chinese

3.You might be reading the book 特工酷女神. The language used by the author should be avoided in formal Chinese. I suggest you to throw this book into rabbish.